# Where to place special functions receive() & fallback()?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, conventions

```
receive() external payable {
    fund();
}
fallback() external payable {
    fund();
```

I want to find  out where exactly should these special functions be wrriten; should they come before the contract or at the tail end of the contract and why. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can technically place these special functions anywhere in your contract without any issues.

However, if you want to follow the Solidity [style guide as referenced in the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/style-guide.html), these functions should directly follow the constructor before any other functions:

> Order of Functions: Ordering helps readers identify which functions they can call and to find the constructor and fallback definitions
> easier.
>
> Functions should be grouped according to their visibility and ordered:
>
> constructor
>
> receive function (if exists)
>
> fallback function (if exists)
>
> external
>
> public
>
> internal
>
> private

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was really helpful.